# Not Used Recently (NUR) Page Replacement Algorithm

Tags: java, c++, c, operating-system

How to implement NUR (Not used recently page replacement algorithm) using any high level programming language (c, c++ or java)

Comment: Show us what you tried, Where you got stuck and seek our help. **Settle on a single language.**

Comment: I will be frank, I have never even tried to implement it, It is a part of virtual memory page replacement techniques, and as part of my learning process I was hoping to get links on how to implement them or, get even get a complete implementable code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually Page Replacement Algorithms have a `buffer` and `pages` to put into the `buffer`.

Buffer size is fixed to a value say 4. Now we keep on adding pages into the buffer, If they are already in the buffer we ignore them and go for the next page to be inserted.

If they are not in the buffer. We have to insert into it if there is space. If there is no space then we search for a replacement element. In this case the least Frequently used.

How do we calculate the least frequently used?
Using a count array.

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 4;
    int []buffer = new int[size];
    int []bufferCount = new int[size];
    int[] pages = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,2,3,4,6,1,2,1,5,1};
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("For page: "+pages[i]+"\t");
        if((pos = contains(buffer, pages[i])) > 0)
        {
            //already in buffer increment the count
            bufferCount[pos] ++;
        }
        else
        {
            //choose the element with least usage and remove it
            int toRemove = getLeastUsed(bufferCount);
            bufferCount[toRemove] = 1;
            buffer[toRemove] = pages[i];
        }
        printBuffer(buffer);
        System.out.print("\t");
        printBuffer(bufferCount);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static void printBuffer(int[] buffer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++)
        System.out.print(buffer[i] + "");
}

private static int getLeastUsed(int[] bufferCount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int index = 0;
    int min = bufferCount[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < bufferCount.length; i++)
        if(bufferCount[i] < min)
        {
            min = bufferCount[i];
            index = i;
        }
    return index;
}

private static int contains(int[] buffer, int key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++)
        if(buffer[ i ] == key)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

}